# Replication of Azure Postgres Flexible Server?

Tags: postgresql, azure, replication, azure-postgresql

Is [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-read-replicas-portal) not supported for Azure Postgres [Flexible Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/)?

> Zone redundancy can not be treated as alternative for Disaster Recovery. Such an important feature is missing. May be until it is in preview?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Abhijeet  Azure Postgres Flexible server supports logical replication. You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-logical#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20Database%20for%20PostgreSQL%20-%20Flexible%20Server,objects.%20Logical%20replication%20allows%20fine-grained%20control...%20More%20) for more details. Let me know if you have additional queries.

Regards,
Oury

Answer (score 1):

If by "replication" you mean "read replicas" then indeed this is **currently not supported**.

High Availability options, in theory, do implement replication, but as of 10.2022 still do not support read access and are meant for fail-over purposes.

On 12th of Oct 2022 they did announce that they are working on Read Replicas, and that the **feature will enter public preview "soon-ish"** but no specific dates are yet communicated.

See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/ignite-2022-continued-innovation-with-azure-database-for/ba-p/3651653

Answer (score 1):

Read Replicas are now supported in Azure Postgres Flexible servers as of February 2023: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-read-replicas

Logical replication is still supported, however, the built in read replica process will manage replication slot creation and deletion which helps with management and to avoid leaving behind unused replication slots.